# Should ux.stackexchange be a migration target

Tags: feature-request, migration

this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/215833/10563) has a suggestion to migrate to ux.stackexchange. This seems quite reasonable, and ideed its not uncommon to se UX questions here.

Given that programmers and UX are full sites would it make sense to have ux.stackexchange as a migration target?

there is also a ux tag with only 9 questions and a search for ux shows another couple of hundred questions (one of which is already migrated to ux)

Answer (score 3):

The [evidence](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (10Κ+ link) doesn't back this up:

[image]

In the last 90 days there has only been 1 migration to UX.

Looking at graduated sites only, there have been:

- 8 to Super User.
- 7 to DBA (14% rejected)
- 4 to IT Security
- 3 to Ubuntu
- 3 to Game Development (1 rejected)
- 2 to Stats (1 rejected)
- 2 to Web Applications (1 rejected)
- 2 to Webmasters
- 1 to Unix

From this evidence we should be adding Super User, DBA and possibly IT Security before UX.

Comment: Is there some guidance on the number of migration target we should have? i.e. is it actually a problem to have SU DBA and IT security as targets?

Comment: btw I think you are right (+1), going on frequency seems like the right thing to do, but that then raises the question how frequent should a migration be before its an automatic target?

Comment: @jk. - The only limit on migrations is that there can only be a maximum of 5 and one of them must be the site's meta site.

Comment: As for when a site gets added - bringing it up in a question like this is a good start. We can then review the evidence and ask the devs to add one (or more) site(s) to the list

Comment: I feel like we will need a slot for [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) after it graduates (will likely happen in 4-6 months; that's the time at their rate of ~5 questions/day to build a 3K questions backlog)

Comment: @gnat - probably true. In that case we should only add SU and DBA at the moment.

Comment: rather then base it on popularity, I'd say base it on the user. Look at what sites the user has some X amount of reputation and give these as migration target. The "having reputation" requirement to have the option to suggest migration ensures that the user asking for migration has some familiarity with the target and know if it's a good fit there.

Comment: @PieterB - that's a completely different issue and has been brought up multiple times on MSO in the past.

Comment: @PieterB the associated MSO post is [Require minimum reputation on the target site for migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74053/require-minimum-reputation-on-the-target-site-for-migration) (and the various linked posts - its a good starting point).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not opposed to having UX as a formal migration target, but I would like to raise a few points.

- My impression from the close review queue is that we don't have all that many questions that would merit a migration consideration.  ChrisF's link from the 10k tools backs that up to a degree.
- I would want to make sure we (Programmers) really understood what was on-topic and constructive for UX before making them a formal migration target.  Personally, I don't participate on UX so I don't know their norms.  My concern is that I don't want UX to become the dumping ground for UX type questions from Programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  Mostly because I would use it... and that 2<sup>nd</sup> point that GlenH7 makes is key.

I'm just looking through my flags (yea, the declined ones) and would really like to get the stance from UX.SE mods about a few things that I've flagged to migrate.

- [When is it appropriate to use colour in a command-line application?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/216252/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-colour-in-a-command-line-application)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215133/recommended-display-background-brightness-ratio-and-ui-color-schemes
- [Main activity design too busy](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215655/main-activity-design-too-busy) (ok, didn't flag that one)

  > When I took my iPhone programming class we were taught about navigation views and tabbed views. Lately I've been noticing a lot of apps using this alternative style though, for example, the Facebook app.
  >
  > The style is that it has a navigation bar at the top, but in the top-left is an "options" button of some sort. When that's clicked a menu slides out from the left side of the screen to control navigation. I'm not sure what view that is, or if each of these apps are creating a custom view or what. Just looking to get pointed in the right direction here.
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209866/does-an-ugly-computer-messy-interface-affect-productivity (10k link)

  > I'm using a standard Toshiba laptop that's pretty beat up and the poor screen-size/ratio gives off the vibe that all the open programs and windows are cluttered and gives me immense anxiety, which ultimately affects how much I accomplish in a day.
- [How to replace the “beep” in software running of modern computer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42928/how-to-replace-the-beep-in-software-running-of-modern-computer) (migrated)
- [Design Suggestions On A Program](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42423/design-suggestions-on-a-program) (migrated)
- [URL Naming Convention for with Repetitive Letter](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203442/url-naming-convention-for-with-repetitive-letter)
- [Any advice on how to solve the problem of bouncing rate for a professional network [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202060/any-advice-on-how-to-solve-the-problem-of-bouncing-rate-for-a-professional-netwo) (10k link - rejected migration?)

  > I have a tech professional network that connects between talent and those who are looking for talent. The problem I had for the last three years is that most users seem to fly right from the front page. The front page is similar to Linkedin. My question is: it it better to feature all the content right in the front page or leave it as it. The main features of the website are showcased projects & published articles. Right now I am out of ideas on how to establish the network and I already have spend lot of time and money on it. I am starting to think I need to make the front page look like behance featuring projects, articles, answers, jobs, etc.. Please give me your advice as user.
- [What is the name of the view style that the Facebook iPhone app uses? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200217/what-is-the-name-of-the-view-style-that-the-facebook-iphone-app-uses) (10k link - not migrated)
- [Synonym for 'GUI' for non-technical people?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38857/synonym-for-gui-for-non-technical-people) (migrated)
- [Positioning in cross browsers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190932/positioning-in-cross-browsers) (10k link)

  > I'm designing and developing a website for a school project which looks fine on my MacBook Pro in Chrome and Firefox. However, when I try to view it on IE 9 and Firefox on my work's PC, the positioning is completely off. The font size in IE 9 is also really off.

I'm rather glad that there's at least one mod there that says "no" to a lot of these suggestions.  I'd be a bit worried about the quality of the content we'd be migrating if these all *did* go through.